# How to name methods in documentation?

Tags: java, methods, documentation, naming-conventions, naming

When documenting code, I often have to write about methods. But how to name them properly in documentation?

Here is an example:

> To perform this task, use `someMethod()` from `MyClass` class.

There are also alternative conventions I know:

- > (...), use `MyClass.myMethod()`.
- > (...), use `MyClass#myMethod()`.
- > (...), use `myObject.myMethod()`.

Which convention is most commonly used? Are there any official guidelines?

Comment: Are you thinking of a specific language?  The preferred formats often differ.

Comment: @morric It's java, I added tag.

Comment: Ah, not one I'm familiar with I'm afraid.  Checking up on what [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/overview/index.html) use for Java might help though.

Comment: @morric If you know any offical guideline for any C-based language, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the ["Don't make me think"](http://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html) maxim, I'd suggest using the following format:

```
To perform this task, use the someMethod method from the MyClass class.
```

This format makes it clear what the target method and class is.

The other suggested formats e.g. :

```
(...), use MyClass.myMethod().

(...), use MyClass#myMethod().

(...), use myObject.myMethod().
```

Requires the user to understand the context in which "." or "#" is being used.

Hence remove the need for the user to pause to think about what they are reading and just use the (almost universal in the programming domain) words "method" and "class" to aid clarity and remove any possible ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use:

```
MyClass#myMethod()
```

because something similar is in the **Ordering Multiple Tags** section:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

```
...
@see Class#method(Type, Type,...)
@see Class#method(Type id, Type id,...)
@see package.Class
@see package.Class#field
@see package.Class#Constructor(Type, Type...)
@see package.Class#Constructor(Type id, Type id)
@see package.Class#method(Type, Type,...)
@see package.Class#method(Type id, Type, id)
...
```